# Using FFMPEG to use mutiple static images

Tags: ffmpeg

I know how to combine a single image with an mp3 to create a video like this

```
"ffmpeg.exe" -loglevel 0 -loop 1 -i c:\path\foo.jpg -i c:\path\foo.mp3 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 0 -c:a copy -shortest c:\path\foo.mkv
```

How can I make ffmpeg create a video using multiple images that it cycles through at regular intervals, or even randomly?  Basically I want to use more than one image in a video rather than just 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the examples from the wiki to [create a slideshow from images](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images).

For example:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/3 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -c:v libx264 out.mp4
```

Keep in mind that all images must have the same size!
In my test the resulting `mp4` file was approximately the same size as the sum of the input files;

```
> du out.mp4
768 out.mp4
> du -c *.jpg|grep total
648 total
```

Note that photos from a digital camera are generally a *lot* bigger than even a HD movie, so you might want to scale the images.
This can be done using the [scale](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling%20%28resizing%29%20with%20ffmpeg) filter, or with an external program like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/). In my example I scaled the images before making a movie out of them.